# 3D Line/Vector intersection point of Rect3D/Plane

Tags: c#, wpf, math, vector, 3d

I have a `Point3D` and direction `Vector3D` inside a `Rect3D` BoundingBox. I want to extend the Point unitl it "hits" the `Rect3D` and then **get the point that extends the vector by 50**. Can someone help me to get to the method to Calculate this?

Something like:

```
public Point3D CalculatePoint(Point3D innerPoint, Rect3D rect, double extendOutside)
```

[image]

Comment: You can extend your point in any direction and the answer for your question will be a surface (not a single point). Otherwise you should specify a vector (direction) of the extension. And better to ask such questions in the http://math.stackexchange.com/, because they are not related to the C# and WPF.

Comment: I asked here because I cannot transform this math knowledge into a c# code or a c# method. Thats why i asked here.

Comment: What math knowledge are you talking about? You have not stated a problem yet clearly.

Comment: Math knowledge how to calculate the "blue" Point outside of that Rectangle. What is not clear for you?

Comment: As @shfire noted, there are infinite number of blue points until you define ray direction or give other information

Comment: I have a start Point3D, Vector3D for direction and Rect3D bounding box. What other information you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're given a box and define it according to its 8 vertices A-H with its 6 faces defined for example as:

```
ABC
ADE
FBC
FGH
DGH
ABE
```

and a line defined by a direction vector `<vx,vy,vz>` and point `(x0,y0,z0)`
you could just go through each of them and get the 2 different points where the line intersects. So given a point, direction vector and 3 vertices of the box...

```c#
//p0 is point on line
//direction is direction vector of line
//A,B,C are points on plane
Vector3 lpIntersect(Vector3 p0, Vector3 direction, Vector3 A, Vector3 B, Vector3 C){
    Vector3 n = (B - C).cross(C - A);
    Vector3 num = (p0-A)*n;
    Vector3 denom = direction*n;
    if((num.x==0 && num.y==0 && num.z==0) ||
       (denom.x==0 && denom.y==0 && denom.z==0))
        return Vector3(0,0,0);
    return num/denom;
}
```

Once you have the 2 points call them `(Ax,Ay,Az)` and `(Bx,By,Bz)` and an equation for the line like

```
x = x0 + vx*t
y = y0 + vy*t
z = z0 + vz*t
```

you can check to see which point is going in the direction that you gave by plugging in the above points and solving for `t` to get for example `(x-x0)/vx` and if `t>=0` then the point is going in the direction you gave else it's the other point:

```c#
if (((Ax-x0)/vx)>=0){
    x = Ax + vx*50;
    y = Ay + vy*50;
    z = Az + vz*50;
}
else{
    x = Bx + vx*50;
    y = By + vy*50;
    z = Bz + vz*50;
}
```